# How to check whether a batch script is running in a Windows slave or not from Jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I want to check if a batch script is running in a Windows slave from Jenkins. I have figured out a way to  do this from the command prompt by executing below command:

`tasklist /v /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq title_batch_script"`

However, that command is not working if I run it using Jenkins "Execute Windows batch command" build step. I guess the reason is the below limitation.

> NOTE: "WINDOWTITLE" and "STATUS" filters are not supported when querying a remote machine.

I tried also with Jenkins powershell plugin with the below command and I don't see the WINDOWTITLE/MAINWINDOWTITLE value. The same command is showing MAINWINDOWTITLE if I run directly in the Widows machine.

`Get-Process | format-table id,name,mainwindowtitle –AutoSize`

May I know if there is a way to overcome this problem? or a different way to find out if a batch script is running or not?

Comment: You need to list the command lines used to launch each process, and search for the entry that has the name of your batch file in it. There's more than one way to do that. WMIC comes to mind, but I don't have time to look up the syntax.

Comment: @jwdonahue: Thanks for the input. That was exactly my question. How to do that from a remote machine? WMIC does not give windowname (https://superuser.com/questions/1080774/how-to-get-window-title-information-from-cmd-in-wmic).

Comment: You don't need the window name (unless your batch script changes that?). You're looking for the name of batch file in the command line that launched the process. You can get that with WMIC, powershell and at least one other tool I don't recall the name of. So for each running process where cmd.exe is the image name, search for the batch file name in the command line that was passed to cmd.exe.